# Execution halted when knitting in RStudio

Tags: r

I´m new at R. I was trying to knit a Rmd file in RStudio into a pdf, but it presents the following error:

Quitting from lines 17-20 (projeto_final_20220429.Rmd)
Error in .External2(C_dataviewer, x, title) : unable to start data viewer
Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> View
Execution halted

The code written in those lines was this:

```
library(readr)
despesas_municipios_saude_educacao <- read_csv("despesas_municipios_saude_educacao.csv")
View (despesas_municipios_saude_educacao)
```

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: I don't think `View()` works with knitting as it tries to open a new window.

Comment: You could consider using something like `knitr::kable(despesas_municipios_saude_educacao)` to produce a formatted table in your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On MacOS, `knitr` attempts to load the X11 library in order to view the data frame, which fails because knitr isn't designed to interact with an end user. Regardless of the underlying operating system, since `utils::View()` is meant to work in a windowing environment (e.g. RStudio, RGui, R Tools for Visual Studio, etc.), it can't be used to print a data frame in an R Markdown document.

````
---
title: "Error with View()"
output: html_document
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## A header

Here is a reproducible version of the stackoverflow question [Execution Halted when Knitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72068679/execution-halted-when-knitting-in-rstudio). 


```{r mtcars}
data(mtcars)
View(mtcars)

```
````

...generates the following error:

[image]

To display a subset of data in a markdown file, one can use `head()` instead of `View()`.

````
---
title: "Error with View()"
output: html_document
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## A header

Here is a reproducible version of the stackoverflow question [Execution Halted when Knitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72068679/execution-halted-when-knitting-in-rstudio). 


```{r mtcars}
data(mtcars)
head(mtcars)

```
````

...and the output in HTML:

[image]

We can improve the look of the output by turning off `echo` on the R chunk used to print the table, and use `knitr:kable()` to format the data frame.

We use the following R Markdown code, including the `"pipe"` argument to appropriately space the columns in the output.

````
We can make the output look nicer with `knitr::kable()`.

```{r kableVersion,echo=FALSE}
library(kableExtra)
kable(head(mtcars),"pipe")

```
````

...and the output renders like this in HTML:

[image]

Comment: Hi Len, thank you for your answer! Using head solved the problem for those lines. However, it reported another error when reading pipe simbol %>%.

Comment: DanielleCGS - the pipe error is a different problem. Please post a new question and include the code you used and the error message. Also, if my answer solved your original problem, please accept it.